# Cassandra realtime data query error

Tags: cassandra

I get a problem with Cassandra as below:
- Sys has 4 nodes (DL80, 64G RAM, 4SSD)
- One table contains about 200k records. This table is realtime update about: 200 record updated per second.
- Web app sometime do query full table for cache and meet exception timeout or tombstone warning.
Can anyone guide me to solve this problem?
Many thanks.

Comment: More information: replica fator=2, this table has one partition key value to hold all records in one node.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank Mr Jeroen Heier.

Answer (score 2):

So I read this:

> One table contains about 200k records.  This table is realtime update about: 200 record updated per second.

...and then this:

> this table has one partition key value to hold all records in one node.

The main problem I see, is that you are storing too many rows in a single partition.  Cassandra has a max of 2 billion cells per partition.  I don't know how many columns you have, but even if you haven't hit that limit, I expect that queries to that partition would eventually get slower and slower.  Especially since you're updating rows in-place.

This is also another red flag:

> Web app sometime do query full table

Querying all rows in a table is something that Cassandra was just not designed to be good at.  Supporting this query is probably why you put everything in a single partition, but there are problems with that approach, as you are finding out.

I don't know what your table looks like, but that is where you need to make some adjustments.

- If you really do need to query all rows in a table, there are several other databases out there which do this better than Cassandra does.
- Try not to update data in-place.  As Cassandra has a log-based, append-only storage engine, you're not actually "updating" anything.  Updates and inserts are synonymous, and simply write a new value for the key.  The old data is obsoleted, and is still there until compaction runs.
- The single partition key approach simply does not scale.  If you're doing that, you might as well just use a RDBMS.  If your data is time-based, then building a partition key with a "time bucket" would distribute better.
- Most problems with Cassandra come from bad data models (table definitions).  It's not like Oracle where someone can "tune the database" by changing some config settings to make everything run better.  There is no amount of config that can help a bad data model.

Comment: Thanks Mr Aaron very much. Our system logs all time seri data collected from sensors (more 10kk recs/day). Data is splited one table (9 columns) each hour and good for query. The table above contains lastest status of sensors (32 columns). When use SQL Server for storing this table, the performance is not enough for 200 recs updated/sec. Cassandra accepts this update freq but not good in full table query. I will try to split this table in multi partitions.